# file association in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, file-association, modern-ui

Associating a file to a program should be easy in Windows. However, i find it rather difficult when I'm working on Windows 8. associating a file to a desktop application that I install on my computer is easy because the whole operation is entirely the same with that in the previous Windows releases. What I find rather difficult is associating a file to a Metro apps that I download from the store. So far, I have been using Multimedia 8 (a metro app) to open my video files. However, this app cannot handle particular files-like *.dat-that can be associated easily to desktop video applications, such as media player classic and the like. When I try to associate my DAT files to Multimedia 8, there is indeed a "***look for another app on this PC***" option at the bottom of the "open with" pop up. But alas, I cannot figure out how to locate my Multimedia 8 app to which I want to associate my DAT file (as well as other video files that are not yet associated to this metro app). If anyone of you knows how to locate those metro apps, please tell me. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are at C:\Program Files\WindowsApps (the directory is hidden; you don't have read permissions by default).

Comment: I think I should choose "look for an app on the store"

Answer (score -1):

Use the Application [DefaultProgramEditor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/) to change the associations:

[image]

> *Default Programs Editor makes it easy to fix file association settings in Windows, including context menu items, icons, and descriptions. Also: autoplay settings and default programs settings ...all without fiddling around in the registry.*

Comment: Does this work with Metro apps as required by the OP?

Comment: DPE doesn't really have Metro apps support yet :/

Comment: ok. I haven't tried it. Contact the creator of the tool and ask him for support.